# Three.js : rotate cube and track faces positions

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, cube

I have a cube with colors or textures on faces.

I rotate it but I need to keep track of the position of the colors on the faces after each rotation.

For example, at the start, green is top, blue in front, and red is left.
So by clicking on "get position", I should get "gbr".

I click on "rotate".

Then the function getPosition() should return "rbn" (for red on top, blue on front, none on left).

Is there a way with three.js to do it?

Do `cube.material`, `cube.geometry.vertices`, `cube.geometry.faces` or anything else have this information?

Here is all the code :

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true
});
renderer.setSize(500, 500);
document.getElementById('cube').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = -2;
camera.position.y = 2;
camera.position.z = 4;

var material = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#000000'
  }), // right
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#FF0000'
  }), // left
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#00FF00'
  }), // top
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#000000'
  }), // bottom
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#0000FF'
  }), // front
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#000000'
  }) // back
]
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), material);
scene.add(cube);

var domove = false;
var stoprotation;

animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (domove) {
    cube.rotation.z -= 0.05;
    if (cube.rotation.z <= stoprotation) {
      domove = false;
    }
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
} // animate

function rotate() {
  if (domove) {
    console.log('SKIP : currently rotating');
    return;
  }
  stoprotation = cube.rotation.z - Math.PI / 2;
  domove = true;
} // move

function getPosition() {
  console.log(cube.material);
  console.log(cube.geometry.vertices);
  console.log(cube.geometry.faces);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="cube" width="300" height="300"></div>
<a href="javascript:getPosition()">get position</a><br>
<a href="javascript:rotate()">rotate</a>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this? looking to do something similar myself at the moment

Comment: yes, i did it another way : init a variable for position, for exemple : let pos = ['r', 'g', 'b']. Then simply update it in rotate(), then return it in getPosition()